# How to avoid problem with displayed-name in react?

Tags: reactjs

On verbal production I get error: Component definition is missing display name  react/display-name

```
const MyButton = React.forwardRef(({ onClick, href }, ref) => {
     return (
       <a href={href} onClick={onClick} ref={ref} style={{color: "#fff"}}>
         in my statement is mistake
       </a>
     )
   })
```

I do not understand why because this work fina at developer mode.

Comment: Hello, Welcome to SO. Can you please update your snippet to match the exact case or can you please update it to be more clear so that we can help you out!

Comment: This is a part of code to avoid problem with next/link. I have it between ``` <link href="/"> <MyButton /> </Link> ```

Answer (score 1):

Well, I used the automatic answer from VSC and the following snipped

```
  // eslint-disable-next-line react/display-name
  export const MyButton = React.forwardRef(({ onClick, href }, ref) => {
      return (
        <a href={href} onClick={onClick} ref={ref} style={{color: "#fff"}}>
         FFF ZZZ SSS
        </a>
      )
    })
```

Topić closed, I hope, I would help someone in future.